# c# how to make a very long float array usable

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert tracker.js to c# and one of the things they have is a very long array of floats

You can see an example here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/master/build/data/mouth.js

However when I try to define this in c# as a variable using `float[] mouth = new float[] {25f,15f,-1.4372119903564453f,13f,0f,2f,0f /*etc this goes on a long time*/};`
Monodevelop grinds to a halt/crashes (I am using MonoDevelop because I am trying to do this for Unity).

Any ideas how I should do this?

Comment: As long as you are not restricted by licensing, you could also use https://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/features/unitytools-vs.aspx (VS plugin for unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, text editors don't handle very long lines well. Simply split the statement up into multiple lines.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try... so there is not a problem with having a float[] that will be as long as the Float64Array in the link I posted? I was concerned that I was doing something fundamentally wrong in someway (i'm a bit of a noobie)

Comment: Its a damn long array, its gonna take me like an hour to split it up... Is there a tool I can use?

Comment: Long arrays aren't all that uncommon, so it shouldn't be a problem (but there could of course be a bug in MonoDevelop). Use any text editor that supports regex search and replace with backreferences in the replacement, and search that array for e.g. `(([^,]*,){10})` and replace by `\1\n`; this should insert a newline after every tenth comma.